# How to highlight a column in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following graph and I want to highlight the columns (both) for watermelons as it has the highest juice_content and weight. I know how to change the color of the columns but I would like to WHOLE columns to be highlighted. Any idea on how to achieve this? There doesn't seems to be any similar online.

```
fruits <- c("apple","orange","watermelons")
juice_content <- c(10,1,1000)
weight <- c(5,2,2000)
df <- data.frame(fruits,juice_content,weight)
df <- gather(df,compare,measure,juice_content:weight, factor_key=TRUE)
plot <- ggplot(df, aes(fruits,measure, fill=compare)) + geom_bar(stat="identity", position=position_dodge()) + scale_y_log10()
```

[image: I would like to highlight the whole columns for watermelons.]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `geom_area` to highlight behind the bars. You have to force the x scale to discrete first which is why I've used `geom_blank` (see this answer [geom_ribbon overlay when x-axis is discrete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16410974/geom-ribbon-overlay-when-x-axis-is-discrete)) noting that `geom_ribbon` and `geom_area` are effectively the same except `geom_area` always has 0 as ymin

```
#minor edit so that the level isn't hard coded
 watermelon_level <- which(levels(df$fruits) == "watermelons")

AreaDF <- data.frame(fruits = c(watermelon_level-0.5,watermelon_level+0.5))


plot <- ggplot(df, aes(fruits)) + 
  geom_blank(aes(y=measure, fill=compare))+
  geom_area(data = AreaDF, aes( y = max(df$measure)), fill= "yellow")+
  geom_bar(aes(y=measure, fill=compare),stat="identity", position=position_dodge()) + scale_y_log10()
```

[image]

### Edit to address comment

If you want to highlight multiple fruits then you could do something like this. You need a data.frame with where you want the geom_area x and y, including dropping it to 0 between. I'm sure there's slightly tidier methods of getting the data.frame but this one works

```
highlight_level <- which(levels(df$fruits) %in% c("apple", "watermelons"))

AreaDF <- data.frame(fruits = unlist(lapply(highlight_level, function(x) c(x -0.51,x -0.5,x+0.5,x+0.51))),
                     yval = rep(c(1,max(df$measure),max(df$measure),1), length(highlight_level)))
                       


   
AreaDF <- AreaDF %>% mutate(
  yval = ifelse(floor(fruits) %in% highlight_level & ceiling(fruits) %in% highlight_level, max(df$measure), yval)) %>%
  arrange(fruits) %>% distinct()
                       

plot <- ggplot(df, aes(fruits)) + 
  geom_blank(aes(y=measure, fill=compare))+
  geom_area(data = AreaDF, aes(y = yval ), fill= "yellow")+
  geom_bar(aes(y=measure, fill=compare),stat="identity", position=position_dodge()) + scale_y_log10()
plot
```

[image]

Comment: FYI `geom_col()` would be equivalent to `geom_bar(stat = "identity")`

Comment: @Sarah what if I want to highlight "apple" too?

Comment: Hi @JohnnyTon updated with one way to make it work with apple and watermelons highlighted

Comment: @Sarah Hi, thanks a lots. But I actually have way more columns that need to be colored (~30 more). Do I need to change the function? `function(x) c(x -0.51,x -0.5,x+0.5,x+0.51)` this part.

Comment: No it should be fine. You just have to add the names of the ones you want highlighted to the highlight_level e.g. `highlight_level <- which(levels(df$fruits) %in% c("apple", "watermelons","pears","strawberries")` or whatever you have in the df and it should work fine

Comment: @Sarah I got some diagonal lines connecting the highlighted columns. (ie., ideally it should be empty in those columns). Any idea why this happens?

Comment: and my y-axis also increase a lots (not the data value, just the axis.)

Comment: Ah, I assume the diagonal happens if there's two highlighted columns next to each other? I didn't think about that possibility and could definitely make ` function(x) c(x -0.51,x -0.5,x+0.5,x+0.51)` return some unexpected diagonals. I'm not 100% sure how to update

Comment: Okay. I've updated the edit section with an extra check on AreaDF. So it doesn't go back to 0 if there are two highlighted side by side. Also apparently if you have two points the same in the area call it sums them which was causing the high axis which is also fixed. You will need `library(dplyr)` for this code

Answer (score 8):

An option is to use `gghighlight`

```
library(gghighlight)
ggplot(df, aes(fruits,measure, fill = compare)) +
    geom_col(position = position_dodge()) +
    scale_y_log10() +
    gghighlight(fruits == "watermelons")
```

[image]

---

In response to your comment, how about working with different `alpha` values

```
ggplot(df, aes(fruits,measure)) +
    geom_col(data = . %>% filter(fruits == "watermelons"),
        mapping = aes(fill = compare),
        position = position_dodge()) +
    geom_col(data = . %>% filter(fruits != "watermelons"),
        mapping = aes(fill = compare),
        alpha = 0.2,
        position = position_dodge()) +
    scale_y_log10()
```

[image]

---

Or you can achieve the same with one `geom_col` and a conditional `alpha` (thanks @Tjebo)

```
ggplot(df, aes(fruits, measure)) +
    geom_col(
        mapping = aes(fill = compare, alpha = fruits == 'watermelons'),
        position = position_dodge()) +
    scale_alpha_manual(values = c(0.2, 1)) +
    scale_y_log10()
```

Comment: Great idea! But the juice_content and weight are now unclear for the apple and orange... I have 2 ideas with this: 1. is it possible to change apple and orange columns into grey and black, so I am able to distinguish between juice_content/weight. 2.(preferred) highlight the WHOLE columns, including the background grid, for watermelons.

Comment: @JohnnyTon I see. I've made an edit to show another option.

Comment: you could also save the separation of data frames and double `geom_col` call by a logical statement within `aes`: `ggplot(df, aes(fruits,measure)) +
  geom_col(data = df,
           mapping = aes(fill = compare, alpha = fruits == 'watermelons'))  +
  scale_alpha_manual(values = c(0.2,1))`

Comment: @JohnnyTon You can *upvote* (using the arrow symbols) as many answers as you like but you can only *accept* (setting the green checkmark) one answer. Which answer you finally accept is your call and usually refers to the answer that addressed your original question best. Don't worry about choosing one answer over the other, there's no hard feelings:-) Stack Overflow is about building a comprehensive database of good and diverse answers. Especially when it comes to R, there is usually more than one solution.